# Node. Bypass auth for images on Login screen

Tags: node.js

I am using background image on the login page but it is not getting loaded when deployed to heroku. It works well on Localhost. When I open the debugger window and open the image url in the browser it redirects to login screen. How can I avoid auth check for background image on login screen.

The login in template code is as below:

```
div(class="container" style="background-image:url(../images/school-wallpaper.jpg);height:650px;width:100%")
        form(class="form-signin" method="post")
            h2(class="form-signin-heading") Please sign in
                label(for="inputEmail", class="sr-only")
                    Email address
                input(type="email", id="inputEmail", name="email" class="form-control", placeholder="Email address", required, autofocus)
                label(for="inputPassword", class="sr-only") Password
                input(type="password", id="inputPassword", name= "password", class="form-control", placeholder="Password", required)
                br
                button(class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block", type="submit") Sign in
                #error
                    if error
                        label.error #{error}
```

And server side implementation is:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    if(req.url.indexOf("/login")==0)
      next()
    else{
      if(req.session.userProile){
        next();
      }
      else{
        res.redirect('/login');
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you've hardcoded `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, here:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
```

Once deployed to heroku, the host isn't `localhost` any more. I would advice you to store your hostname in an environment variable, that will differ while being in production or development. You can use for example [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) module to make this process more easier.